# NSManagedObject - relationship fault

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship, fault

I have two entities correlated (E1,E2) with a one to many relationship
**E1 <--->> E2** (relationship name: *pictures*)

E1 also has other relationships one to many with different Entities (E3,E4)

When I retrieve the E1 from coredata E1.pictures result:

```
pictures = "<relationship fault: 0x1d5a8c60 'pictures'>";
```

Now,

- I know that this kind of message is not an error :)
- E1.pictures is not empty.
- When I save a new picture and I provide to refresh the E1 managed object ( [E1.managedObjectContext refreshObject:E1 mergeChanges:YES]; ) the E1.pictures is returned back correctly and I can show the images.
- I try to make the  refreshObject:E1 before to take the count, but it doesn't work

I assume that I retrieved the object correctly.
I would like to know before save a new picture how many pictures have the E1
and obviously show the pictures (but without a picture count... I don't go anywhere)

Could I be missing something? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: [Core Data Faulting and Uniquing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)

The word 'fault' in Core Data essentially just means that the object of the relationship has not been fetched yet. If you access the `pictures` property of your `E1` instance, the fault will be fired and you will see the `E2`object.

Also, calling refresh on a Core Data object will set it's relationships back to faults, which is why you are seeing that.

Comment: thanks ChrisH, following your suggestion about the refreshObject I found a solution. The issue was that a refresh 'invalidate' the E1.pictures.
The solution I found until now is to move the code where I use the E1.pictures.count before the refresObject code.
Now I'm reading the link you suggest to me to better understand